# How do I reference an Array element in a List of Arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

I have created a `LinkedList` of `String` arrays:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String[] one = new String[10];
    String[] two = new String[10];
    String[] three = new String[10];

    LinkedList<String[]> myList = new LinkedList<String[]>();

    myList.add(one);
    myList.add(two);
    myList.add(three);

}
```

My question is how do I now access an element of one of the arrays.  For instance, I can access (or in the example print) the entire array element via:

```
System.out.println(myList.get(0));
```

But how do i access the first element in the `String` array that is owned by `myList.get(0)`?  I tried everything like `myList.get(0).[0]`, but I can't figure out how to access an element in an array, when the array is an element of a linked list.

Comment: as an observation, you named your `LinkedList` "array", it's actually quite wrong, `array` is a direct access data structure while `linkedlist` is sequential access. it's a major difference.

Comment: Yes.  I know.  I was trying to created a "dumbed" down version of the code to get right to the point.  But you are correct, this is not good practice.  I changed the name to "myList" instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
array.get(0)[index];
```

That should do the trick.

`array.get(0)` returns an array, all you have to do is add your index after it (no dot to separate).

Just the same way you would use `one[index]`.

Comment: Nice. I was thinking about String [] arr = array.get(0) and then get arr[0].